# Create a component containing other components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a "container" component in Angular which contains other components and formats them / orders them in a predefined way (like a dashboard).

I would like to pass the components to the container as an input array like this:

```
 <container
    [inputComponents] = "['MapComponent', 'EventsListComponent', 'FileListComponent']"
 >
 </container>
```

My "container" component should show the Map and the Lists like a Dashboard with special formatting and so on.

I did already lots of research but couldn't find a good solution for this. I don't think passing angular components via input parameter is a good solution?

I found this on Stack Overflow which is very similar to my problem:
[Angular: Pass Component to a Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933783/angular-pass-component-to-a-component)

But I don't want to change any of the already existent components to extend an abstract widget component. Is this really the only way to realize this?

Comment: Your container component should have ng-content and then just pass those components as templates like: `<container><map-component></map-component></container>`. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691

Comment: In this Tutorial you learn the basics of Angular https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3. Also how to use components within a component

Comment: @ritaj Thanks for your help. But with your solution, I can only pass one single component to my containerComponent. I want to be able to pass multiple components though.

Comment: @RonaldHaan Thanks for the tutorial. It's nice but not helping with finding the answer to my problem.

Comment: You can pass multiple components like that

Comment: @ritaj As far as I have seen, you can use it like that: `<container><map></map><list></list></container>` and select it within the container component using `<ng-content select="map">` and `<ng-content select="list">`. But my container component does not know which components it will get. So this is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

check this example

item.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() order?: string;

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

item.component.html

```
<ng-template>
 <p>
  item works!
 </p>
 <ng-content></ng-content>
 </ng-template>
```

item-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, QueryList, ContentChildren, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemComponent } from '../item/item.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.css']
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(ItemComponent, {descendants: true}) 
  items?: QueryList<ItemComponent>;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
    
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
      
  }

}
```

item-list.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.order}}
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></ng-template>
</p>
```

finally:
app.component.html

```
<app-item-list>
  <app-item  order="2">
    test2
  </app-item>
  <app-item order="1">
    test1
  </app-item>
</app-item-list>
```

[Complete Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j6yhe8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)